# Rails Devise Ajax Login 401 Unauthorized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm trying to perform authentication in my Rails app with Ajax calls and Devise. I've set up my environment according to many resources doing the same thing, but I keep getting 401 Unauthorized errors.

I've configured my `routes.rb` file to point to my custom `SessionsController`

```
class SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController

  respond_to :json

  def create  
    self.resource, resource_name = authenticate(auth_options, :teacher)
    set_flash_message(:notice, :signed_in) if is_navigational_format?
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
    respond_with resource, location: after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # Attempts to authenticate the login request, first as a Teacher and
  # then as an Admin.
  def authenticate(auth_options, resource_name)
    # First login attempt using Teacher scope
    resource = warden.authenticate(auth_options)

    # If authentication failed, retry using Admin scope
    if resource.nil?
      resource_name = :admin
      request.params[:admin] = params[:teacher]
      resource = warden.authenticate!(auth_options.merge(scope: :admin))
    end

    # Return resource and resource name, required for Devise sign_in method
    [resource, resource_name]
  end
end
```

My situation is a little unique since I'm trying to have the same controller handle the login for two Devise models. Currently, this works exactly as expected, as I can log in through `/teachers/sign_in` (default Devise form) with both teacher and admin credentials. When I try and log in through that route, my rails output looks like:

```
Started POST "/teachers/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-13 21:15:26 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"HRIuJCj/FoHYEPX+boKC60s4oau6OyWz1NY8ZbC0ruLRLfGOs6esElHEYSdLHesZjXBk4LGTffE5Ilq1p5pjqQ==", "teacher"=>{"email"=>"teacher1@teach.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0"}, "commit"=>"Log in"}
Teacher Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "teachers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "teacher1@teach.org"]]
 (0.2ms)  BEGIN
 SQL (0.3ms)  UPDATE "teachers" SET "last_sign_in_at" = $1, "current_sign_in_at" = $2, "sign_in_count" = $3, "updated_at" = $4 WHERE "teachers"."id" = $5  [["last_sign_in_at", "2015-10-14 04:03:00.121311"], ["current_sign_in_at", "2015-10-14 04:15:26.801062"], ["sign_in_count", 16], ["updated_at", "2015-10-14 04:15:26.802083"], ["id", 1]]
 (0.7ms)  COMMIT
```

However, when I try and log in through my Ajax calls, I get:

```
Started POST "/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-10-13 21:09:06 -0700
Processing by SessionsController#create as */*
Parameters: {"teacher"=>{"email"=>"teacher1@teach.org", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "remember_me"=>"0", "authenticity_token"=>"m3+HyUZ+fbQ3d70X2LtL5Wff2b/6lAe++psXGM2T6dtXQFhj3SbHJ76jKc79JCIXoZcc9PE8X/wXb3HI2r0kkA=="}}
Teacher Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "teachers".* FROM "teachers" WHERE "teachers"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "teachers"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "teacher1@teach.org"]]
Admin Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "admins".* FROM "admins" WHERE "admins"."email" = $1  ORDER BY "admins"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["email", "teacher1@teach.org”]]
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 136ms (ActiveRecord: 6.1ms)
```

In the second case, it seems like it's performing the exact same (correct) SQL query, but it's failing to authenticate. I've been hitting this problem for hours and don't really know how to proceed from here.

Comment: please checkout that the params sent to the server is correct something is wrong here. in the first server log. the `non-ajax request` you send `"email"=>"teacher1@teach.org"` while the sql is executed and search for `"teacher1@bizworld.org"`

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, I changed the actual emails when copying to this post and obviously wasn't careful enough :) It's always the same email when testing locally, so I've updated the logs accordingly

Comment: if you looked at the difference between the two logs you will find that the first one the correct one the server finds the record in the `teachers` table, that why it doesn't query the `admins` table. while in the second log the `ajax one` you will find that the `admins table` has been queried after the `teachers table` which means the entry can't be found inside the `teachers table`. please show us the `ajax code` the `js code` you use to make `ajaxable request` make sure you are sending the correct password and username

Comment: My devise setup currently tries to authenticate as a teacher; if that fails, it'll try to authenticate as an Admin. That's why in the second case you see the Admin lookup table attempt. The issue is that I can't seem to figure out why it's even attempting to try the Admin lookup, the since the Teacher SQL query looks exactly the same. 

However, you can tell from the logs that the username being passed to both cases is the same ("teacher1@teach.org") and though the password is filtered out I'm sure that matches as well since I've tried multiple times.